# Reputation line graph only has one of three lines

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, network-profile, reputation-graph

So I found [the cross-site repuation line graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/955702?tab=reputation). Ignoring the known bug/feature that cross-site association is adding 100 points to the entirety of the SO line, there's another problem: neither my MSO nor my Gaming reps are on the graph. What's up with that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Accounts must have a minimum of 200 reputation to appear in this graph

The start of the graph will strangely be before 200, but this is because it also displays around 1 week before you hit 200.

Comment: Is this explained somewhere, or is it a hidden feature?

Comment: @Toomai Sure right [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109985/reputation-line-graph-only-has-one-of-three-lines/109986#109986). Joking aside the [user flair](http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair) and the [user leagues also](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/) have that you-need-200--for-this-to-be-turned-on-for-you so Pubby8 is surely right.

Comment: @Toomai Trying to view the graph when you have no accounts higher than 200 will display "Accounts must have a minimum of 200 reputation to appear in this graph"

Comment: Okay then. I might think of opening a request later to display a message of "Only accounts of 200+ will be displayed".

Comment: This is correct