# Rep line graph: Say "only 200+ accounts displayed" at all times

Tags: feature-request, network-profile

As discovered/discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109985/reputation-line-graph-only-has-one-of-three-lines/), the cross-site reputation graph doesn't show accounts that have less than 200 reputation. The problem is that, unless you have zero accounts over that bar, it doesn't tell you that. I think the "Accounts must have a minimum of 200 reputation to appear in this graph" notice should appear either (A) at all times or (B) if you have any accounts below 200.